How to chose minimise position for Text in SwiftUI?
I am using this code for having 1 line text string in my swiftui app.
 Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
  .lineLimit(1)

The result of this is: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consec..."
I want something like this: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit ame... id est laborum"

I don't understand what the question title is saying. Do you mean .truncationMode(.middle)?

yes, that was what I wanted.

Use truncationMode to change where you want the text to be truncated at. In this case, you want the .middle of the text to be truncated.
Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.")
    .lineLimit(1)
    .truncationMode(.middle)

